# How to count the unique occurrence for multiple paths within a list based on the index position

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list which consists of multiple path, IE:

```
/project/task1/sub1/info1
/project/task1/sub1/info2
/project/task1/sub2/info1
/project/task1/sub2/info2

/project/task2/sub1/info1
/project/task2/sub1/info2
/project/task2/sub2/info1
/project/task2/sub2/info2
```

How could I count the number of occurrence by index if the string is different within the paths? Such as for above I am expecting to get this:

```
idx0 = 1 (only project exist)
idx1 = 2 (task1 & task2)
idx3 = 2 (sub1 & sub2)
idx4 = 2 (info1 & info2)
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution via list and dictionary comprehensions:

```
lst = ['/project/task1/sub1/info1',
       '/project/task1/sub1/info2',
       '/project/task1/sub2/info1',
       '/project/task1/sub2/info2',
       '/project/task2/sub1/info1',
       '/project/task2/sub1/info2',
       '/project/task2/sub2/info1',
       '/project/task2/sub2/info2']

lst_expanded = [x.split('/')[1:] for x in lst]

idx = {i: len(set(j)) for i, j in enumerate(zip(*lst_expanded))}

# idx = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
```

Comment: thanks you for your prompt  answer, can you please explain your code? I do not understand that especially the zip part.

Comment: Sure. `lst_expanded` gives a list like [['project', 'task1'], ['project', 'task1']]. `zip` iterates `lst_expanded` piecewise to give [('project', 'project'), ('task1', 'task1')]. `enumerate` adds a counter `i`. `set` makes the collection unique. `len` counter number of items.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = ['/project/task1/sub1/info1', '/project/task1/sub1/info2', '/project/task1/sub2/info1', '/project/task1/sub2/info2', '/project/task2/sub1/info1', '/project/task2/sub1/info2', '/project/task2/sub2/info1', '/project/task2/sub2/info2']
new_s = map(lambda x:x.split('/'), s)
final_output = {"idx{}".format(a):len(set(i)) for a, i in enumerate(zip(*new_s))}
```

Output:

```
{'idx3': 2, 'idx2': 2, 'idx1': 1, 'idx0': 1, 'idx4': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to print from idx0 to idx4 while I just has 4 strings within the path, seems to be extra field there?

Comment: @Grace unless you are using new input of a different format, this is similar output to `{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}`, except the keys are replaced with the corresponding `'idx'`

Comment: Thank you very much Ajax, appreciated!